# Versioning History filter

Tags: sharepoint-online, version-history, sharepoint-list-filter

Is there any way to add a filter like we have on a normal list on Sharepoint Online?

**Version History:**

[image]

**Normal list:**

[image]

Comment: I dont understand you .. what you exactly want? Filtering in view based on Version for all documents or list and filtering for one document? You can add filtering, if you add Version column to the view.

Comment: @ZdeněkVinduška I want a view where i can filter all versions (and date) for a specific document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add filtering, if you add Version column to the view.

Comment: Yes I know, but I want a view where i can filter all versions (and date) for a specific document.

Comment: There is no such a filter for all versions for specific document, you have only the Version History list, which you have on first screen.